# making calculations with money

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

so I am making a program that calculates the weight of a book and charges you according so.

as you know in decimal number the 0 is not considered in calculations so how do I make the computer consider it when it is dealing with money?

ps is it possible to make the computer display  the pound sterling sign (£) on the program?

edit: sorry guys what i meant was like a number like 1.50 will just be written as 1.5 on a computer but money wise the 0 is important so how would make sure that the program includes it?

Comment: I guarantee you that the computer acknowledges the existence of `0`.

Comment: yes, you can make it show £ if your environment (charset, font, etc.) supports it. [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RBWs2b5icC1W3VgJ).

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal number the 0 is not considered in calculations"? I don't understand your question.

Comment: Look up `std::precision`.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you mean printing because otherwise the '0' makes no difference to the compiler.

Use the following:

`printf("%.2f ", 123.45678);`

The computer can display '£' but I am not sure where youre displaying it. If it is within a print out statement, you should be able to just write it out.

Next time just be a little more careful about what you are asking.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Oops, you are absolutely correct! I should have proof read before submitting

Comment: Actually you have it right. I was thinking about something else. I am just going to delete the comment.